# Visualforce: Using HTML Entity as an attribute value

Tags: visualforce

I'm using an html entity as a data attribute that, through CSS, will render an icon:

```
<span data-icon="&#xe6a8;">
Delete Token
</span>
```

CSS:

```
[data-icon]:before { content: attr(data-icon); margin-right: 0.75em; }
```

Something seems to be preventing the entity from actually rendering though and instead shows the raw entity value:

[image: Delete Icon Not Rendering]

We use this approach in other applications without issue, so I'm thinking it must be related to Salesforce.  Is that right?

Comment: Are you using a literal for that entity or merging it in? Can you share the CSS as well?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I've added it to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Salesforce is escaping the character code and hence it is being displayed as plain text.
The data-icon attribute would work if the character code is not escaped. However, I am not sure how to achieve that.

I tried the following code by first getting the correct unescaped character into a span and on page load added it to the data-icon attribute and it worked.

```
<apex:page id="myPage" >
  <style>
        [data-icon]:before {
            font-family: icons;
            content: attr(data-icon);
            speak: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        function setIcon(){
            var mychar = document.getElementById("myPage:myChar").innerHTML;
            var elem = document.getElementById("testSpan");
            elem.setAttribute("data-icon", mychar);
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            setIcon();
        };

    </script>


  <apex:outputText style="display:none;" id="myChar" value="&#x21dd;" escape="false" ></apex:outputText>

  <span id="testSpan" style="font-size: 50px">
       Delete Token
    </span>
</apex:page>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This seems like a lot of work to do something so small - but I'll keep it in mind as an option.